# Is every model of $\Gamma$ a model of $Cn(\Gamma)$?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Is every model of $\Gamma$ a model of $Cn(\Gamma)$ ?

$Cn(\Gamma)=\{\sigma:\Gamma \models \sigma\}$
This is the set of all sentences logically implied by $\Gamma$ .

This could help me to understand some facts of elementary first order logic.

Comment: If by $\models$ you meant $\vdash$, then the answer is yes. Are you working with propositional, or predicate logic, or in some other context? (Details of the reason why this is true vary accordingly to the context.)

Comment: So, what is the question? If a sentence is true is all models, then it is true in every model.

Comment: (By the way, the $Con(\Gamma)$ notation is not ideal; it is typically used to mean something else, namely, the formal assertion that $\Gamma$ is consistent.)

Comment: I corrected the question, i think now it is well written

Comment: Does "logically implied" mean "provable"? What is your definition of "logical implication"?

Comment: If you still mean $\vDash$, then the question is still trivial. At least with $\vdash$ you'd be wondering about Completeness, but I think you're getting confused by notation. Something being a model of $\Gamma$ *just is* being a model of everything that any model of $\Gamma$ is a model of...

Comment: Γ logical implies σ iff every model of Γ is a model of σ

Comment: What would it mean for the implication you wonder about to be false?

Comment: Yes, now i understand, i was just mixing notation, thank both of you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Here's why:

by definition given a set of formulas $\Gamma$ and a formula $\varphi$ then 
$$\Gamma \models \varphi$$
if for every $M$ which is a model of $\Gamma$ ($M \models \Gamma$) then $M$ is also a model for $\varphi$ ($M\models \varphi$).

By definition $\sigma \in Cn(\Gamma)$ iff for every structure $M$ such that $M\models \Gamma$ we have that $M \models \sigma$.

So for every $\sigma \in Cn(\Gamma)$ and every structure $M$ such that $M \models \Gamma$ we have $M \models \sigma$, i.e. every model of $\Gamma$ is a model of every formula in $Cn(\Gamma)$ (i.e. $M \models Cn(\Gamma)$).

Comment: Thank you, I was confused with the notation, you helped me a lot